# The timeout specified has expired : error reading status line from remote server

Tags: java, spring, proxy, jboss, wildfly

I have **proxy server timeOut** error on my proxy http appache this is log of error  .

when i want to connect to the IHM application i hava this error of proxy

1- is it problem on network or heap space java
2- or problem is what ??

```
[Fri May 20 09:20:20.279361 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28344:tid 140348751816448] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.115.197.238:4022] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010
[Fri May 20 09:20:20.279419 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28344:tid 140348751816448] [client 10.115.197.238:4022] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by
[Fri May 20 09:20:34.408359 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28782:tid 140348852528896] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.115.197.238:9753] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010
[Fri May 20 09:20:34.408394 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28782:tid 140348852528896] [client 10.115.197.238:9753] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /dv/
[Fri May 20 09:20:45.657358 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28343:tid 140348938123008] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.115.197.238:14327] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010
[Fri May 20 09:20:45.657424 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28343:tid 140348938123008] [client 10.115.197.238:14327] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /dv/
[Fri May 20 09:38:35.756355 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28782:tid 140348818958080] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.115.197.238:63822] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010
[Fri May 20 09:38:35.756426 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28782:tid 140348818958080] [client 10.115.197.238:63822] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /dv/
[Fri May 20 09:41:46.315376 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28343:tid 140348802172672] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.115.197.238:16448] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010
[Fri May 20 09:41:46.315417 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28343:tid 140348802172672] [client 10.115.197.238:16448] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /dv/
[Fri May 20 09:42:07.083348 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28344:tid 140348860921600] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.115.197.238:25284] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010
[Fri May 20 09:42:07.083398 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28344:tid 140348860921600] [client 10.115.197.238:25284] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /dv/
[Fri May 20 09:42:46.385371 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28782:tid 140348751816448] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.115.197.238:37965] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010
[Fri May 20 09:42:46.385430 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28782:tid 140348751816448] [client 10.115.197.238:37965] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /dv/
[Fri May 20 09:42:46.617361 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28343:tid 140348726638336] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.115.197.238:41858] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010
[Fri May 20 09:42:46.617396 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28343:tid 140348726638336] [client 10.115.197.238:41858] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /dv/
[Fri May 20 09:43:46.842360 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28343:tid 140348726638336] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.115.197.238:41858] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010, referer: https://webdei.ca-sa.group.gca/dv/
[Fri May 20 09:43:46.842405 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28343:tid 140348726638336] [client 10.115.197.238:41858] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /favicon.ico, referer: https://webdei.ca-sa.group.gca/dv/
[Fri May 20 09:44:01.343364 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28344:tid 140348835743488] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.179.128.16:57900] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010
[Fri May 20 09:44:01.343401 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28344:tid 140348835743488] [client 10.179.128.16:57900] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /dv/
[Fri May 20 09:44:12.908369 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28782:tid 140348860921600] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.115.197.238:12952] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010
[Fri May 20 09:44:12.908402 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28782:tid 140348860921600] [client 10.115.197.238:12952] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /dv/
[Fri May 20 09:45:00.223421 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28343:tid 140348818958080] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.115.197.238:32123] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010
[Fri May 20 09:45:00.223470 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28343:tid 140348818958080] [client 10.115.197.238:32123] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /dv/
[Fri May 20 09:46:00.321372 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28343:tid 140348818958080] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.115.197.238:32123] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010, referer: https://webdei.ca-sa.group.gca/dv/
[Fri May 20 09:46:00.321422 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28343:tid 140348818958080] [client 10.115.197.238:32123] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /favicon.ico, referer: https://webdei.ca-sa.group.gca/dv/
[Fri May 20 09:48:37.417392 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28344:tid 140348718245632] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.115.197.238:54871] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010
[Fri May 20 09:48:37.417446 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28344:tid 140348718245632] [client 10.115.197.238:54871] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /dv
[Fri May 20 09:50:19.005350 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28343:tid 140348735031040] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.179.130.14:39624] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010
[Fri May 20 09:50:19.005379 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28343:tid 140348735031040] [client 10.179.130.14:39624] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /dv
[Fri May 20 09:54:44.290371 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28339:tid 140348701460224] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.115.197.238:12461] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010, referer: https://lp063mid8555.cloud.group.gca:9443/
[Fri May 20 09:54:44.290406 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28339:tid 140348701460224] [client 10.115.197.238:12461] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /dv, referer: https://lp063mid8555.cloud.group.gca:9443/
[Fri May 20 09:55:07.491345 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28344:tid 140348844136192] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.115.197.238:22342] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010
[Fri May 20 09:55:07.491381 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28344:tid 140348844136192] [client 10.115.197.238:22342] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /dv/
[Fri May 20 09:55:10.283376 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28782:tid 140348785387264] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.115.197.238:23449] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 10.179.133.81:8010
[Fri May 20 09:55:10.283439 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 28782:tid 140348785387264] [client 10.115.197.238:23449] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /dv/
[Fri May 20 09:57:11.942249 2022] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 28334:tid 140349164377920] AH00295: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri May 20 09:57:25.967718 2022] [:notice] [pid 69658:tid 139668069406528] ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.2 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Fri May 20 09:57:25.967780 2022] [:notice] [pid 69658:tid 139668069406528] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.6.3"; loaded version="1.6.3"
[Fri May 20 09:57:25.967784 2022] [:notice] [pid 69658:tid 139668069406528] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.41 "; loaded version="8.41 2017-07-05"
[Fri May 20 09:57:25.967786 2022] [:notice] [pid 69658:tid 139668069406528] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.7"
[Fri May 20 09:57:25.967788 2022] [:notice] [pid 69658:tid 139668069406528] ModSecurity: Status engine is currently disabled, enable it by set SecStatusEngine to On.
[Fri May 20 09:57:26.115740 2022] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 69712:tid 139668069406528] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri May 20 09:57:26.132494 2022] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 69712:tid 139668069406528] AH00292: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2n configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 20 09:57:26.132551 2022] [core:notice] [pid 69712:tid 139668069406528] AH00094: Command line: '/tools/list/product/apache-2.4.46/bin/httpd-f conf/http.conf'
```

My server backend on java with wildfly  :

i see a heap space java not enough but after proxy server error

what can be the problem .

the log of my server wildfly is below  :

```
    09:21:51,361 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-4) SQL Warning Code: 4222, SQLState: 01000
09:21:51,361 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-4) [jcc][t4][10433][12420][4.25.23] The requested security mechanism is not supported by the server.  Retry the connection using an alternative security mechanism ERRORCODE=4222, SQLSTATE=01000
09:45:37,590 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("read-resource") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "m.war")]): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

09:45:43,154 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("read-resource") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "m.war")]): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

09:49:42,397 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0019: Deployment dv_ae-4.0.8.ear was previously deployed by this scanner but has been removed from the server deployment list by another management tool. Marker file /tools/list/product/wildfly-9.0.2/server/srvdv/deploy/dv_ae-4.0.8.ear.undeployed is being added to record this fact.
09:49:43,338 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0019: Deployment mid.war was previously deployed by this scanner but has been removed from the server deployment list by another management tool. Marker file /tools/list/product/wildfly-9.0.2/server/srvdv/deploy/m.war.undeployed is being added to record this fact.
09:57:20,604 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.4.3.Final
09:57:20,937 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
09:57:21,099 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 9.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.2.Final) starting
09:57:23,049 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'job-repository-type' in the resource at address '/subsystem=batch' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
09:57:23,054 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 12) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=DB_dv' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
09:57:23,652 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
09:57:23,686 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
09:57:23,713 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
09:57:23,836 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 2 core threads with 16 task threads based on your 1 available processors
09:57:23,847 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
09:57:23,930 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.2.5.Final)
09:57:23,939 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
09:57:23,976 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
09:57:24,012 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
09:57:24,021 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver (version 4.25)
09:57:24,092 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
09:57:24,107 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
```

**my timeout and proxy timeOut are 60**

Can you explain me why i have this error .